# Hibernate Criteria fetchType JOIN with one-to-many relationship shows different behavior with and without aliases

Tags: hibernate, join

I have two entities Forest & Tree. Forest has one-to-many with Trees and I mapped it as a List with FetchType as LAZY and it is a bidirectional. My intention is to load the Forest and Tree objects (eagerly) using the Criteria API. I am observing a different behavior with Criteria when using aliases vs not using aliases.

When I am not using alias as below, I see a single query is being fired and able view fetch both Forest and Tree objects.

```
 Criteria criteria = ses.createCriteria(Forest.class);
 criteria.setFetchMode("trees", FetchMode.JOIN);
 criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
 criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "Forest-Six"));
```

The query that gets fired is following “Query:[“`select this_.id as id1_1_1_, this_.name as name2_1_1_, this_.version as version3_1_1_, trees2_.FOREST as FOREST6_7_3_, trees2_.id as id1_7_3_, trees2_.id as id1_7_0_, trees2_.”COUNT” as COUNT2_7_0_, trees2_.FOREST as FOREST6_7_0_, trees2_.index as index3_7_0_, trees2_.name as name4_7_0_, trees2_.version as version5_7_0_ from Forest this_ left outer join Tree trees2_ on this_.id=trees2_.FOREST where this_.name=?”], Params:[(1=Forest-Six)`]”.

The same criteria api when used with aliases, I see multiple queries being fired as below:

```
 Criteria criteria = ses.createCriteria(Forest.class, "forest");
 criteria.createAlias("forest.trees", "trees");
 criteria.setFetchMode("trees", FetchMode.JOIN);
 criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
 criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("forest.name", "Forest-Six"));
```

The queries being fired:
Query:[“`select this_.id as id1_1_1_, this_.name as name2_1_1_, this_.version as version3_1_1_, trees1_.id as id1_7_0_, trees1_.”COUNT” as COUNT2_7_0_, trees1_.FOREST as FOREST6_7_0_, trees1_.index as index3_7_0_, trees1_.name as name4_7_0_, trees1_.version as version5_7_0_ from Forest this_ inner join Tree trees1_ on this_.id=trees1_.FOREST where this_.name=?”], Params:[(1=Forest-Six)]`

and for each forest it fires below (N queries; 1 for each forest):

Query:[“`select trees0_.FOREST as FOREST6_7_0_, trees0_.id as id1_7_0_, trees0_.id as id1_7_1_, trees0_.”COUNT” as COUNT2_7_1_, trees0_.FOREST as FOREST6_7_1_, trees0_.index as index3_7_1_, trees0_.name as name4_7_1_, trees0_.version as version5_7_1_ from Tree trees0_ where trees0_.FOREST=?”], Params:[(1=7)]`

I am using Hibernate 5.0.4 and not sure if this is the right behavior. If not, I would really like to understand why JOIN fetch is not working with aliases.

Comment: The answer is in the SQL: your alias creates an inner join. And fetching needs a left join. Why do you create an unused alias in the first place?

Comment: @JBNizet In fact,that is what I wanted to understand, why is different (multiple) SQL statements getting generated while using aliases. Because I think creating aliases should not effect the fetch strategy or result in multiple SQLs being issued. Regarding the unused alias, are you referring to alias `trees` that is created for association `forest.trees`? If so, I think it is used in the next line `criteria.setFetchMode("trees", FetchMode.JOIN);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. Although you shouldn't join as JB Nizet pointed out, even if you remove that `createAlias` call, when using an alias Hibernate doesn't issue a SELECT statement with a JOIN.

There's a [Jira issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7842), which you can track to follow the progress on this one.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. That removes a lot of my confusion. For a moment I got too suspicious on Criteria usage as we use it a lot in our projects. Also the JIRA link has "Affects Version/s: 3.6.10" only. May need to include 5.0.4 as well so that it gets more priority, I believe.

Comment: I added a test case against the 5.0.6 and it still replicates. Good catch.